# Maps literally read < and > instead of the actual character

Tags: vimrc, linux, key-bindings, linux-arch

#### Situation

- Entire `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap a <CR>
```

- Action: user types `ia` to enter insert mode and type `a`
- Expected result: a carriage return is entered into the document
- Actual result: the characters `<CR>` are typed

I've discovered that `a` can be any sequence of characters, and `<CR>` can be
any special character denoted with `<>`, and this behavior still persists.

I swear it wasn't doing this a few days ago.

#### Origin

Specifically, I'm trying to include in my `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<Esc>ko
```

but it did not work.

To debug, I tried

```
inoremap { {<CR>}<Esc>ko
```

so Vim did not have to listen for any enter keys.

When Vim typed out `{<CR>}<Esc>ko` in my document, I became aware of the nature
of the issue.  I believe Vim never activated the initial map because it did not
receive the set of characters `<CR>` after the `{`.

Netrw also stopped receiving the enter key and Vim just goes to the next line
when I intend to select a directory.

#### About my setup

I'm operating a relatively fresh install of Arch Linux, running off of a
bootable USB flash drive.  The USB flash drive is plugged into a standard Dell
latitude E5510 laptop with Windows 7 on the hard drive, though it is not being
used.  However, when I use the Windows 7 on the hard drive and use Vim, this
problem does not occur.  The problem occurs both in the system's console, and in
XTerm in i3wm, whether the "VT220 Keyboard" setting is turned on or off, whether
"Old Function Keys" is on or off.

[image: NeoFetch output]

Comment: check your 'cpo' settings, escpecially look for `:h cpo-<` and `:h cpo-k`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Alright, I've checked and found that < and k flags are on. I tried turning them off (confirmed they were off via "set cpo" and seeing they were no longer there) and nothing changed.

Comment: Those flags do not need to be there (and there are not, if you start from vim --clean). So make sure to remove those flags and **then you need to rerun your mapping commands**, because those settings apply when the mapping is defined.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Well, that was easy. Added "set nocp" to .vimrc. THANKYOU!!! I'm relatively new to the website, so should you make an official "answer," or should I?

Comment: Welcome to Vi&Vim SE. +1 for posting a (first?) question with plenty of details and for having spent time looking for a solution on your own. If I had a suggestion for future questions it would be to "trim the fat" a bit. What I mean by that is to be a little less conversational and a little more succinct without losing any of the important details. I actually don't mind your style but you want to keep as many eyeballs on your question as you can. Cheers.

Comment: Okay, so I should have clicked on your profile first....you've been hear for a little while and this is your second question. Lol. The rep points threw me. Everything else I wrote stands, though! :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20641/maps-literally-read-and-instead-of-the-actual-character#comment36081_20641), you need to make sure `cpoptions` does not contain the `k` and `<` flags before defining your mappings (this explains why netrw broke too).

The likely culprit is that vim was running in compatible mode (this should not be the case if you have a `.vimrc` file, but it's possible to do some funky things with the invocation to end up in compatible mode). I do not recommend putting `set nocompatible` in your `.vimrc` though.

Instead, I would investigate why `compatible` was set, or at least why `cpoptions` had those flags.

A simple trick to discover if they were set from a file is `:verbose set compatible? cpoptions?`.