# Mapping using <Esc> writes "<Esc>" in insert mode rather than switching to normal mode

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, normal-mode

I have the following line in my .vimrc:

```
inoremap kj <Esc>
```

It had been working fine, ie it returned me to normal mode. But now it inserts the string "< Esc>" (I use the initial space here just so my post displays properly) into the file at the cursor and I remain in insert mode.

My full .vimrc is as follows

```
syntax on
set smartindent
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
inoremap kj <Esc>
nnoremap zz :update<cr>
nnoremap qq :wq<cr>
nnoremap mm :vsplit<cr><C-w><C-w>
" Ctrl-j/k deletes blank line below/above, and Alt-j/k inserts."
nnoremap <silent><C-j> m`:silent +g/\m^\s*$/d<CR>``:noh<CR>
nnoremap <silent><C-k> m`:silent -g/\m^\s*$/d<CR>``:noh<CR>
nnoremap <silent><A-j> :set paste<CR>m`o<Esc>``:set nopaste<CR>
nnoremap <silent><A-k> :set paste<CR>m`O<Esc>``:set nopaste<CR>
nnoremap <Enter> i<Enter><Esc>
nnoremap <S-Enter> o<Esc>
nnoremap <S-tab> i<tab><Esc>l
nnoremap <C-x> ^i#<Esc>
nnoremap <C-d> yy^i#<Esc>p
```

Why has this started happening and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
output of the following commands

```
:set compatible?
nocompatible

:set cpoptions?
cpoptions=aAbBcCdDeEfFgHiIjJkKlLmMnoOpPqrRsStuvwWxXyZ$!%*-+<>;
```

EDIT2:
I'm running Arch Linux, 4.19.56-1-lts, and the latest version of Vim.
Output of "vim --version":

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jul  4 2019 23:02:48)
Included patches: 1-1635
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +tcl/dyn
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
-browse            +gettext           +num64             +textprop
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     +perl/dyn          -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           +python/dyn        +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildmenu
+cursorbind        +lua/dyn           +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      -sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.30/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lelf -lnsl    -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.30/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/5.30/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc   -L/usr/lib -ltclstub8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lm
```

Comment: Is it normal that you mention the line `inoremap kj <Esc>` but it doesn't appear in your vimrc? (There is an equivalent line `inoremap jj <Esc>`).

Comment: Please post output of the following commands: `:set compatible?` and `:set cpoptions`. (Edit the question to include the output.) Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I changed the shortcut to jj to see if that would make a difference and forgot to change back, fixed the typo in my post now

Comment: also please check `:verbose set cpoptions?`

Comment: Ah this looks interesting. `:verbose set cpoptions?` shows
`Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/vim.vim line 989`, (in addition to the list of characters above). The offending line in the listed file reads `let &cpo = s:keepcpo`
So maybe this means that, when compatible mode is later switched off because of my vimrc, the cpoptions don't change to the Vim options as they normally would, but instead remain as the Vi options?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: You're in `compatible` mode, add this to the top of your `.vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible
```

Key specifiers using the `<...>` syntax are incompatible with the traditional `vi` and are specific to Vim.

This particular feature can be enabled by removing `<` from the [`'cpoptions'`] setting, which controls compatibility options. The `<` option is documented as:

> Disable the recognition of special key codes in `<>` form in mappings, abbreviations, and the "to" part of menu commands.  For example, the command `:map X <Tab>` results in X being mapped to:
>
> - `<` included:   `<Tab>`  (5 characters)
> - `<` excluded:   `^I`     (^I is a real )

When in compatible mode, all options in `'cpoptions'` are set, while only a handful (and not including `<`) are set in `nocompatible` mode.

So ensuring you're in `nocompatible` mode is the first step in making sure these mappings are going to work for you.

Comment: I'm not convinced: [`:h 'compatible'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27compatible%27) says `off when a vimrc or gvimrc file is found` so putting `set nocompatible` in your .vimrc should not change vim's behavior and since OP's vimrc doesn't contain `set compatible` I would be curious to understand how they ended up in compatible mode.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. My shortcuts now behave as expected again. However, based on the response to `:set compatible?` it seems I wasn't in compatible mode, but that somehow the `<>` characters were still in the list of compatible options. Is that right?

Comment: Having `<` in `'cpoptions'` is the behavior you *don't* want... Makes the `<>` keys become literal symbols, instead of specifications for special keys.

Comment: ludog It would be interesting to try to understand why you were in compatible mode, did you have a `.vimrc` when you tested this? As @statox mentioned, having one should make Vim default to nocompatible mode, so wondering why that wasn't working for you... Did you have one at the time? What version of Vim were you running?

Comment: ludog also please accept the answer, so this can indicate it solved your issue. This might help others who are looking for the same issue in the future.

Comment: Yes I understand it was the undesirable behaviour. The reason I haven't accepted this answer yet is that it says I was in compatible mode and I wasn't sure that is right. Doesn't the output from `set compatible?` that I have put in the EDIT to my post indicate that I wasn't in compatible mode?

Comment: ludog Huh I just noticed that... On the other hand, your `'cpoptions'` is set like if you were in compatible mode. Perhaps try to [debug your vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/18609) to try to understand what's happening? Also, please post more information about your system (Vim version, OS, whether you have the Vim runtimes installed or not, etc.) as that can maybe help explain why this is working the way it is...

Comment: I included the OS and Vim version info in my most recent edit. I notice that the file at /etc/vimrc is a duplicate of the file at ~/.vimrc (or it was until I added the line you suggested). Could that have had anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96538/discussion-between-ludog-and-filbranden).

Comment: See also my comments at this question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20641/71